TS unable to infer appropriate parameter type
In summary, I'm trying to define a function like function.prototype.bind() but one which uses a function as follows:
/**
 * @template T
 * @template {any[]} A
 * @template {any[]} B
 * @template R
 * @param {(this: T, ...params: [...A, ...B]) => R} func
 * @param {() => [T, ...A]} getParams
 */
export function bindReturn(func, getParams) {
  /** @param {B} params */
  return (...params) => func.call(...getParams(), ...params)
}

However, when I use it as follows, TS is not able to correctly infer the type of parameter B
/**
 * @param {string} a
 * @param {number} b
 * @param {boolean} c
 */
function f(a, b, c) {
  return /** @type {const} */ ([a, b, c])
}

const f2 = bindReturn(f, () => /** @type {const} */ ([null]))

Here, the type parameter B of bindReturn is inferred as any[], instead of [a: string, b: number, c: boolean]. I used [...A, ...B] because it is also used in the definition of .bind() in lib.d.ts, so I was expecting the above to have no issues. Is something wrong with what I've written, or is it just an issue with the compiler?

Oof, this would be a lot easier to process if you wrote TS and not JS.

The issue is that the function is being inferred from the parameters instead of the other way around. What we need to do is infer the parameters type from the passed function using Parameters utility type the infer the our returned function params from that.
// Borrowed from OP's comment/appraoch
export type TupleSlice<T extends any[]> =
  T extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]
  ? [] | [First, ...TupleSlice<Rest>]
  : [];

function bind<
  T,
  A extends (...params: any[]) => any,
  B extends TupleSlice<Parameters<A>>
>(
  func: A,
  getParams: () => [T, ...B]
) {
  return (...params: Parameters<A> extends [...B, ...infer I] ? I : never) => func.call(...getParams(), ...params) as ReturnType<A>;
}

function foo(a: number, b: string) { }

const foo2 = bind(foo, () => [null])
foo2(1, 'foo') // (a: number, b: string)

Playground
Note: This answer initially used a generic type Rest<Tuple, Partial> to get the rest of the parameters tuple, but that needed casting the tuple returned by getParams, hence the comments about casting. Directly defining and inferring the parameters of the returned function with a conditional type (also from OP's approach in the comments), circumvents that.

I think the OP question writing () => /** @type {const} */ ([null]) is equivalent to () => ([null] as const) which works also, and so the "catch" is already expected by the question. But my JSDoc expertise is lacking.

Yeah, @jcalz, if they're ready to cast the return value then no issues. One thing I noticed is that if I try the approach with as const instead of casting the tuple type (with more than the first this parameter), it doesn't work. It's because Rest can't work with a readonly array for its partial. So casting to the tuple type seems to be the only way with this appraoch.

Thanks @Brother58697. I later went down a similar route too. And as @ jcalz mentioned, I already expected the casting to be needed.

While testing it out, I figured the answer above doesn't fully work, particularly when returning two or more params. See example here. bind(foo, () => [null, ""] as [null, ""]) works (although not fully), which is wrong, while bind(foo, () => [null, 8] as [null, 8]) doesn't work, and it should.

@Abdulramonjemil Use [null, number] instead of [null, 8]. Casting to a literal makes it too narrow for Rest to work.

@Brother58697, Can you take a look at this which is what I'm currently using https://tsplay.dev/NnYVqw
Doesn't require casting. But has a tiny catch which can be seen in the playground

It also errors when wrong params are passed, as seen here. Just gives an error of ... may be instantiated with another subtype ... and need // @ts-expect-error

I gave it a shot, but I'm stumped (I like TupleSlice btw), maybe @jcalz can get around this error.

@Abdulramonjemil got it to work by treating the function itself as the generic type and using Parameters to use a narrower type for P. Here.

@Abdulramonjemil I edited the answer to reflect the correct reasoning behind the issue

@Brother58697, I saw that you used never for the other side of the conditional for the parameter type of the returned function (where I used []). I'm not sure which is better, but it seems TS doesn't always infer [] as the type of the spread ...params as expected. See an example here. Instead of inferring [], it takes the never type, making the function uncallable. I think it's weird behaviour though.

From the example, it can be seen that TS infers [] some of the time (first example in playground linked above), and never at other times (second example).

@Abdulramonjemil That's a good find. Looks like, the conditional is going to the else condition. I've narrowed it down to the union of "" | "a" causing the issue. Turns out that [number, "a"] isn't recognized as a partial of [number, 'a' | ''], Overloading doesn't work because instead of a union of the signatures it returns the signature of the last defined function. So I used distributive conditionals to get a union of the parameter tuples (Spread<Parameters>) and again to iteratively spread the partial over the union. Test
